# Troubling starting new silverlight 4.0 project (in f#) from VS2010

Tags: f#, installation, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to protoype a silverlight 4.0 project using F#, and am having issues getting it to install... the silverlight 4 tools for Visual Studio 2010 is barking at me:

> Installation Requirements:
>
> Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Web
>   Developer Express 2010 or Visual Phone
>   Developer Express 2010 that matches
>   the language version of Silverlight
>   Tools 4 must be installed before
>   installation of Silverlight Tools can
>   continue.  Silverlight Tools is
>   available in other languages at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=177432.

VS INfo

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version
>   10.0.30128.1 RC1Rel Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30128 RC1Rel
>
> Installed Version: Professional
>
> Microsoft Visual F# 2010
>   01018-315-4422943-70575 Microsoft
>   Visual F# 2010

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F# for Silverlight 4 is not out yet (though I think it is coming fairly soon).  For the moment you can only use F# for Silverlight 3.

EDIT (May 17, 2010)

The new Silverlight tools are released, go [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=177428) and get an install including FSharp.Core.dll for Silverlight 4.

See also [this blog](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!2097.entry) for a short step-by-step walkthrough.

Comment: lol figures.  Though I have seen a number of allusions to it...  Thank you; I am getting back into the MSFT world after a Java hiatus - can I ask you where you are keeping tabs on the release status etc?

Comment: See http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/  The toolkit release is currently "RC2"; the final "RTM" should include the new F# bits.